# How to iterate through nested xml elements using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have an xml file which includes the nested elements below:

```
<SourceDetails>
    <Origin>Origin</Origin>
    <Identifier>Identifier</Identifier>
    <Version>0</Version>
</SourceDetails>
```

I have already used the function at_xpath to extract the above xml snippet from an xml file which has been stored in a variable. Is it possible to iterate through this variable and store the contents of nested xml elements using Ruby Nokogiri? If so, how is this done?

I would like to append each element within SourceDetails to another variable followed by a forward slash. For the above example, I would like to get the content in the format Origin/Identifier/0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty one. Since I'm not sure how you're storing your variable containing the XML, to be sure I'm getting the actual XML data I actually read the the XML data from a file, which gives us:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = File.open('source_of_xml.xml') { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }

values = []
xml.xpath('SourceDetails').each do |elem|
   values << elem.text.gsub(/\n/, "").split
end

p values.first.join("/") #assing this to variable you want. 

# => "Origin/Identifier/0"
```

Does this help or guide you in anyway?

Comment: The variable does not have xml data, it just contains normal text. Essentially it is a string variable and I want to add values from the nested xml to the end of the string.

Would you happen to know how get values straight from the contents of the xmls tags to a string variable? If you don't that is fine, your answer has definitely helped!

Comment: @NadiyaNelson can you please show how the variable you're working with looks like? Maybe update your question. Because now I'm just assuming the XML data is what's stored in the variable. If you could post how this variable looks like it'd be nice.

Comment: Hi @Emanuel, I have just worked it out, thank you so much for all your help, it is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way

```
require "nokogiri"
xmlFileData = Nokogiri::XML(File.open('./xmlFile.xml'))
dataArr = xmlFileData.at_xpath("//SourceDetails").text.split("\n")
dataArr.delete_at(0)
puts dataArr.join("/").gsub(/(\s+)/, '')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer